# Is 20MB normal for an APK file?

Tags: android, flutter, build, apk, release

I've made the `.apk` file for my project and it's weight is 19.4MB, is it normal?
I used the command:

`flutter build apk --release`
The command does generate and apk file, but, outputs this message:

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20MB is a normal size but most of your App size is contributed by binaries for android-arm, android-arm64 and android-x64. 
In a particular device, only one of the binaries will be used according to the device hardware i.e. abi of the device.

It is recommended to use app bundle because Google automatically creates APK for each abi thus reducing the size of app.

for example Play Store will be create individual apk for android-arm, android-arm64, and android-x64 ABI.

Comment: If I will use app bundles.. I will get 3 files. Do I have to import all of them to a separate application, or the same app?

Comment: Great answer! Do you have any idea of what the difference may be in terms of app bundle size vs apk size?

Comment: Nvm, It is just one file. called: ``app.aab``. Right?

Comment: @TomeR yes only one file will be there.

Comment: @WilsonWilson It all depends on your app i.e. libraries that you have used. Apk holds code for all the abis. So if you four abi it will have core module and then code for all four abis. You can check the exact size for each abi on your Google Play Developer console. Navigate to your application > Release Management > App Releases then click on Manage (On Production or Beta or Alpha release) there you will get an option "Explore App Bundle". Click on it you will exact size of app for each abi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's normal for apk files. You had built the binaries for multiple process support like x64 , arm, etc. that's why size is more in your case. But it does not create any problem. You can reduce the size of your apk by building binaries only for targeted platform on which you want to run your app.